# DateTimePicker Loop Through Weks

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 DateTimePickers: `startDate` and `endDate`

I need to some how loop through all the weeks between those two dates. So for example all the weeks between 02/01/2013 - 02/01/2014.

I basically want the loop to start at 02/01/2013 and increment 7 days on each iteration until it gets to the end date. I've been trying think of a way to achieve this but I can't find a solution.

Is it possible?

**Solved:**

```
for (DateTime i = dateStart.Value; i <= dateEnd.Value; i = i.AddDays(7))
{
    // Do something on each iteration
}
```

Will update answer in 8 hours. Won't let me answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to approach this:

```
        var startDate = new DateTime(2013, 2, 1);
        var endDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 1);

        var totalDays = endDate.Subtract(startDate).TotalDays;

        // Determine the total number of weeks.
        var totalWeeks = totalDays / 7;

        // Initialize the current date to the start date
        var currDate = startDate;

        // Process each of the weeks
        for (var week = 0; week < totalWeeks; week++)
        {
            // Do something

            // Get the next date
            currDate = currDate.AddDays(7);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. This is how I tried it at first but I was positive there was a simpler way. The problem was I didn't understand the `DateTimePicker` as I'd never used it.